# JPA SINGLE_TABLE inheritance from two tables

Tags: java, sql, jpa

```
    <entity class="com.AbstractClass" access="FIELD">
            <table name="TABLE_0"/>
            <secondary-table name="TABLE_1">
                    <primary-key-join-column name="TABLE0_REF_ID" referenced-column-name="TABLE0_ID"/>
            </secondary-table>
            <inheritance strategy="SINGLE_TABLE"/>
            <discriminator-column name="TYPE" discriminator-type="INTEGER"/>
            <attributes>
                    <id name="id">
                            <column table="TABLE_1" name="TABLE1_ID"/>
                            <generated-value generator="GLOBAL_GENERATOR" strategy="SEQUENCE"/>
                    </id>
                    <basic name="name">
                            <column table="TABLE1" name="NAME"/>
                    </basic>
            </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="com.DateClass">
            <discriminator-value>2</discriminator-value>
            <attributes>
                    <basic name="date">
                            <column table="TABLE_1" name="DATE"/>
                    </basic>
            </attributes>
    </entity>
```

I'm using Eclipselink for JPA mapping. I have two problems:

1. When I'm using exact mapping as above eclipselink generating wrong query (wrong table for primary table primary key; I think this is because primary key is in secondary table, but I, can't change this - `TABLE_0` and `TABLE_1` have different primary keys and I can not change database):
   `[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT t0.NAME t1.TABLE1_ID FROM TABLE_0 t0, TABLE_1 t1 WHERE (t1.TABLE0_REF_ID = t1.TABLE0_ID)`
2. To solve this problem i'v used  following `DescriptorCustomizer` (I can't switch primary and secondary tables, 'cause  must be in primary):

   ```
   @Override
   public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
           descriptor.getAdditionalTablePrimaryKeyFields().clear();
           descriptor.getMultipleTableForeignKeys().clear();
       descriptor.addForeignKeyFieldNameForMultipleTable("TABLE_0.TABLE0_ID", "TABLE_1.TABLE0_REF_ID");
   }
   ```

In that case query generating correctly, but i'v got list of multiple instances of the same object:

```
    public class GenericDAO {
            ...
            public List getAll() {
                    CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(entityClass);
                    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
                    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
            }
    }

    new ClassDAO().getAll();
```

Output:

```
13485751-Object_1
13485751-Object_1
13485751-Object_1
13485751-Object_1
....
```

Comment: Sorry, why can't you map table1 as the primary table in JPA?  It doesnt require database changes.  Other than that, the issue seems like you defined the primary-key-join-column going in the wrong direction.

Comment: First of all, I did not switched tables because discriminator-column must be in primary (I didn't notice that it not showing in question), and primary goal was to build orm-mapping without mapping warnings and errors.
And actually I already tried this (had added in customizer `descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().getClassIndicatorField().setTableName("TABLE_1");`). And I thought it did not worked for me. But I mistook exception, thrown during runtime, as mapping exception. So now I'm working out this option.

Comment: And this is the solution.